# laravel 4 modify an input value inside controller

Tags: php, mysql, regex, laravel-4

Okay, this one is a bit tricky and unusual, but I need to do it for one of my project.

so I have 2 routes :

```
Route::get('table/edit',  array('uses'=>'CompanyController@editTable'));

Route::post('table/update',  array('uses'=>'CompanyController@editTableAction'));
```

Now the fields in the database table I'll be storing data are dynamic, So I must take advantage of the :

```
Input::all();
```

Method. There's a hidden input in my form

```
<input type="text" name="database_field_name_user_friendly" value="User Input Some Name" />

<input type="hidden" name="database_field_name" value="" />
```

Now, as you can see,

```
Input::get('database_field_name');
```

is empty. Is there a way I can set the value of this input box inside the controller? I need to process the value from another input field database_field_name_user_friendly . I'll run regex to make it a valid MySQL field name.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For guys like me who want the answer `Request::instance()->query->set('key','value');`

Answer (score 10):

I got the solution just after posting the question :p

Hope this helps someone else! Really very easy. Inside your controller

Let's process the input

```
$database_table_name = strtolower(Input::get('account_database_table_name'));
//make alphaunermic
$database_table_name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $database_table_name);
//Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
$database_table_name = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $database_table_name);
//Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
$database_table_name = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "_", $database_table_name);
```

And then simply set the value! Using Laravel `Input::merge` method

```
 Input::merge(array('account_database_table_name'=>$database_table_name));
```

Thanks!